# use sed with variables in a python script using subprocess

Tags: python, sed

I would like to use sed or tr inside a python script to introduce an ID in the fastafile.

I've tried that but it says syntaxError:

> subprocess.call(['sed\'s/>/>'+identifier+'/g\' <'+path+'>transcriptome')],shell=True)

where identifier and path are variables. It's must be part of a loop where for each ID and introduced path it has to change the tipical fasta format: >isotig123 to >IDisotig123. Each one with their corresponding ID.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, the question so is how can I do it.

Comment: Try printing the string you feed to `call` to see if it matches what you think it is. Also, did you know Python has an `re` module that can be used for regular expression match and replace?

Comment: Python can natively implement both `tr` and any `sed` script, especially a trivial substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
subprocess.call(['sed -e "s/>/>'+identifier+'/g" '+path+' >transcriptome')],shell=True)
```

- replace `\'` by `"` around sed action
- replace the `<` with direct file reference
- add `-e` to use action command

Assuming Identifier does not contain special char `&`, `\`, `/` like in your sample

Answer (score 0):

There is a whitspace missing between the sed command and its arguments. Try this:

```
subprocess.call(['sed \'s/>/>'+identifier+'/g\' <'+path+'>transcriptome')],shell=True)
```